# Python super constructors -- which arguments do you put in the child method?

Tags: python, superclass

I've created an "Animal" class that takes in parameters `name` and `colour`, and a subclass called "Pig" which should inherit `name` and `colour` from "Animal", but should also take a new parameter, `TailType`.

Here's what I've done so far:

```
class Animal(object):
    def __init__(self, name, colour):
        self.name = name
        self.colour = colour

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name

    def set_name(self, newName = ""):
        self.name = newName

    def set_colour(self, newColour = ""):
        self.colour = newColour

    def get_colour(self):
        return self.colour

    def __str__(self):
        return self.get_name() + ' : ' + self.colour

class Pig(Animal):
    def __init__(self, name, colour, tailType):
        super().__init__()
        self.tailType = tailType
```

When I'm initialising the "Pig" class, I'm not sure which parameters to put in the `__init__` definition; should it be `name` and `colour`, or `name` + `colour` + `tailType`?

Also, does this subclass inherit the `__str__` representation method of Animal, or do I have to write that again within the "Pig" subclass?

I'm really not sure about which parameters go where, when I initialise a subclass. I've looked at examples, and they all have very simple cases with one parameter (self).

If I try to do

`john = Pig('John', 'pink', 'curly')`

I get

`TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'name' and 'colour'`.

Superclasses and subclasses make sense conceptually, but when it comes to dealing with their syntax, I'm really struggling.

Note: please don't refer me to a general explanation of what superclass constructors are: I've read a lot of them and still don't really know how to apply them in this situation.

Comment: The problem isn't the arguments to the child class, it's that *you aren't passing them on*. `super().__init__(put, them, here)`. Note that it's showing you this specific line in the traceback for a reason. Also note you shouldn't write getters and setters in Python.

Comment: You pass the superclass constructor whatever arguments it takes.

Comment: You need to be very careful when using `super` with `__init__`. When you call `super().__init(name, color)` from inside `Pig.__init__`, you have *no way* of knowing if the next class in the MRO actually expects arguments for its definition of `__init__`.

Comment: @chepner What do you mean by that? I'm at a very low level atm, so I don't really know what you mean, and I don't know what MRO refers to.

Comment: MRO = Method Resolution Order

Comment: Obligatory reading: [Python's `super()` considered super!](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) and [Python's Super is nifty, but you can't use it](https://fuhm.net/super-harmful/). The second one doesn't actually contradict the first, but highlights some points the first one doesn't quite emphasize enough.

Comment: @chepner Thanks. I'll take a look at these. One problem I have, though, is that every time I read a page on a topic with which I'm not familiar, it always includes examples using functions/methods that I don't understand, and when I look up *those* functions/methods, I am led to more notation that I don't understand. In this case, in your first link, it's the `logging.info('Setting %r to %r' % (key, value))
        super().__setitem__(key, value)` that I don't understand...

Comment: Ignore the log statement. With `__setitem__`, the signature is clear and nobody every changes it: you *know* that `__setitem__`, regardless of which class's definition is called next, will take 2 arguments. With `__init__`, there is no standard. Some classes (`object`) won't allow *any* arguments; other classes expect a specific set of one or more arguments; others will take any arguments you pass and ignore the unexpected ones. (Life would probably be easier if `object` simply ignored any extra arguments it received.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just pass `name` and `colour`.

```
class Pig(Animal):
    def __init__(self, name, colour, tailType):
        super().__init__(name, colour)
        self.tailType = tailType
```

Think of it as `super()` provides me the method from the parent, bound to my object. What does it take as inputs? `name` and `colour`? Let's pass it `name` and `colour`, then.

And yes, `__str__` is inherited like any other method.

Comment: So am I right in thinking that the `def __init__()` part takes all the parameters associated with "Pig", and  `super().__init__()` part takes the parameters that you want to be passed down from the parent class?

What happens if I created an "Animal", and then wanted to make it a "Pig"? Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: Right, except you meant passed down **to** (not from) the parent class.

Comment: I don't know of any easy way to casting your Animal as a Pig. You'd have to do it manually. You could add a class method in Pig to create a Pig instance from an Animal instance and a tailType.

Comment: I thought that child classes inherit from the parent classes, not the other way round?

One more thing:
if I wanted to use `Animal.__init__()` instead of `super().__init__()`, how would I do it?

I've done this:
class Pig(Animal):
    def __init__(self, name, colour, tailType):
        Animal.__init__(name, colour)
        self.tailType = tailType

but `alf = Pig('Alfie', 'pink', 'straight')` results in the error 

`TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'colour'`.

Comment: Also, which notation is best: `super().__init__()` or `Animal.__init__()`?

Comment: I guess Animal.__init__() is not binded to your object, so you'd need to pass it self explicitly. Use the super() syntax, that's what it is here for.

Comment: "I thought that child classes inherit from the parent classes, not the other way round". That's right. And in `Pig.__init__`, `super().__init__()` passes its variable up to the parent (`Animal`)'s `__init__` method. Anyway, I think you get the idea.

Comment: What would happen if I didn't put all the variables into the `super().__init__()` part? Say I used `super().__init__(name)` instead of `super().__init__(name, colour)`.

Comment: Also, in the edX course I'm doing, they are using `Animal.__init__()`. Does it matter?

Comment: "What would happen if I didn't put all the variables into the super().__init__() part?" This is what you do the OP and you get that TypeError due to missing parameters.

Comment: "Also, in the edX course I'm doing, they are using Animal.__init__()." Do they? I don't understand why they do that.